# How can Lightning components be opened from a list view?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, custom-button, list-view, list-button

I am looking to add a custom button to the Account list view that opens a Lightning component. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Bhawna is correct, you cannot call a Lightning Component from a List button directly.
In the past, I have implemented something which may be useful in this scenario.

Step 1:
Create the component you want and make it implement the lightning:isUrlAddressable interface

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:appHostable,lightning:isUrlAddressable" access="global">
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.initialize}" />
<div class="slds-box slds-theme_default">
    Some Stuff Here
</div>
```

```
({
    initialize : function(component, event, helper) {
        var recordId = component.get("v.pageReference").state.c__id;
        console.log('Here is record Id' + JSON.stringify(recordId));
    }
})
```

Step 2:
Create a Hyperlink Formula field on Account.

```
HYPERLINK("/lightning/cmp/c__myComponent?c__id=" + Id, "Click Me!","_self"))
```

Step 3: Add formula field to list view
[image]

Now you can do whatever you need to do with your component and the record Id passed to it - in this scenario, we are just logging it to the console.
[image]

Please let me know if this solution will work for you - it's a nice workaround I have used in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be overriding a standard action (like view, new, edit) with your Lightning Component as described here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_using_lex_s1_action_overrides.htm

Not sure if that fits your use case as overriding will be global and not only triggered from a list view.

Comment: This will not work for me because the standard layout is overridden by a Lightning record page. Please see (and hopefully answer) this post: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/184173/overriding-new-button-while-page-layout-is-overridden-by-lightning-record-page

Answer (score -1):

You can not call a Lightning Component from List Button directly. You need to do it using visual force page. 
You can check the Component developer guide for this. Complete solution is given there.