# Overriding New button while page layout is overridden by Lightning record page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, service-cloud-console, button-overrides, page-override

I have the Account record page (View button) overridden by a custom Lightning record page, and I have set it as the default layout in Service Console. Now if I override the New button with a Lightning component bundle the system keeps giving preference to the app default and ignores my button override.

How can I override the View button with a Lightning record page and override the New button with a Lightning component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So according to the [Summer '17 Release Notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_lightning_action_overrides.htm):

> Action overrides aren’t supported in Lightning console apps, and are
>   silently ignored when invoked. If a Lightning console app user
>   triggers an action that has been overridden, they see the standard
>   action instead.

Comment: I came across this post this week as I'm dealing with a similar but different issue (link below). It seems that action overrides are now respected in console apps as of Spring 18, which is what I'm observing in some of our customer orgs. Wondering if you have experienced the issue that I've described here? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/232085/lightning-component-override-for-standard-new-button-not-always-getting-called