# Lightning component override for standard new button not always getting called

Tags: lightning-aura-components, managed-package, button-overrides

This may not be the best place to post this, but since Salesforce partner support has refused to look at the issue, saying it’s a developer issue that requires premier support, I’m posting here to see if anyone else has experienced this.

We have a lightning component that implements the interface `lightning:actionOverride` and is included in one of our managed packages. It’s used to override the “New” opportunity button in lightning experience. It works as expected for the majority of our customers, however for a handful of customer orgs the lightning component does not fire when the user clicks the “New” button from a related list on the contact. Instead of our component firing, we are seeing the standard Salesforce functionality happening. In these orgs we are also seeing that our component will fire if the user switches to an app that has the navigation style configured as “Console navigation”. We have been unable to repro the issue in our dev/qa orgs, and have submitted a case to Salesforce in the partner community, but they closed it, saying that it was a developer issue and that it required premium support. I’m posting here to see if anyone else has experienced the same issue? If so, any info you could share would be appreciated.